# Jquery data table pdf option not working after path change

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have downloaded data table example  from extras/TableTools/index.html with pdf & excel option. Which is working fine. But after making changes in the path only print option is working and pdf & excel option stops working.

**My Code Header:**

```
<style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
        @import "demo_page.css";
        @import "demo_table.css";
        @import "TableTools.css";
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="TableTools.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready( function () {
            $('#example').dataTable( {
                "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip'
            } );
        } );
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the tabletools swf file path

```
"oTableTools": {
    "sSwfPath": "PATH_TO_SWF/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
}
```

As mentioned in the site [TableTools example - setting SWF path](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/swf_path.html)

> If you aren't using the same directory structure as the
>   TableTools package, you will need to set this parameter.

Comment: If this answer has worked for you, please consider accepting it as the right answer.